# Where is the error in my Code for this array?

Tags: php, html

So I am attempting to use a form to open a php file that contains an array composed of address' and house prices. I have the stylesheet done and all the data form the array. I believe the error resides with my foreach statement however after hours of looking I cannot find my error. The array should be included in a table with a border that is 2px and solid red. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Test 1</title>



<style type="text/css">
    #pricetable {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    #pricetable th, #pricetable td {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>


<table id="pricetable">

<caption>
<h3> Here are all the houses whose prices are between $100000 and $500000: </h3>
</caption>

<tr>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>Price</th>
</tr>

<!-- IDEA 2  -->
<?php
    $lowprice = trim($_POST['lowprice']); 
    $highprice = trim($_POST['highprice']); 
    $user = trim($_POST['user']);
    $pw = trim($_POST['pw']);

$houseprices["123 Elm"]=260000;
$houseprices["96 Otis"]=340000;
$houseprices["9 Windham Place"]=560000;
$houseprices["293 Wilma"]=230000;
$houseprices["6789 Beach"]=800000;
$houseprices["535 Overlook"]=750000;
$houseprices["59 South Lake"]=900000;
$houseprices["19 Ash"]=270000;
$houseprices["6820 Butternut"]=340000;
$houseprices["902 Weston"]=190000;
$houseprices["496 Ervin"]=340000;
$houseprices["316 Pond"]=280000;
$houseprices["7282 Main"]=420000;
$houseprices["561 Billings"]=350000;
$houseprices["117 Peach"]=280000;
$houseprices["2171 Bentley"]=300000;
$houseprices["365 Prescott"]=1120000;
$houseprices["319 Paley"]=310000;
$houseprices["43 Maple"]=150000;
$houseprices["291 Wilson"]=320000;
$houseprices["81 Essex"]=330000;
$houseprices["995 West Lawrence"]=480000;
$houseprices["679 Esther"]=240000;
$houseprices["6890 Patten"]=600000;
$houseprices["53 Lower Pond"]=250000;
$houseprices["4567 Washington"]=170000;
$houseprices["691 Holt"]=1900000;
$houseprices["1234 Main"]=180000;
$houseprices["6 Cherry"]=360000;
$houseprices["639 Perrywinkle"]=190000;
$houseprices["86 Foster"]=1300000;
$houseprices["341 Elm"]=200000;
$houseprices["5122 Bern"]=350000;
$houseprices["688 Maple"]=210000;
$houseprices["64 Oak"]=640000;
$houseprices["874 Marlin"]=220000;
$houseprices["53 Lake"]=190000;
$houseprices["206 Alban"]=310000;
$houseprices["371 Martha"]=420000;
$houseprices["866 Delaware"]=230000;
$houseprices["342 West Lawrence"]=440000;
$houseprices["63 Ashley"]=450000;
$houseprices["49 Tabler"]=260000;
$houseprices["417 Deermill"]=370000;
$houseprices["38 Holt"]=490000;
$houseprices["689 Aspen"]=300000;
$houseprices["4441 Park"]=210000;
$houseprices["8394 North Lake"]=320000;
$houseprices["722 Perry"]=530000;
$houseprices["99 East Ridge"]=260000;
$houseprices["4374 Elderberry"]=270000;
$houseprices["89 Lubbock"]=370000;
$houseprices["12543 Benson"]=380000;
$houseprices["240 London"]=290000;
$houseprices["745 Park"]=390000;
$houseprices["18 Wilson"]=400000;
$houseprices["11 Westgate"]=540000;
$houseprices["4736 East River"]=250000;
$houseprices["4793 Chauncey Circle"]=370000;
$houseprices["3073 West Main"]=280000;

    $name_and_pw_ok = false;
    foreach ($pw as $key => $val) {
        if ($user == strtolower($key) 
            && $pw == $val) {
            $name_and_pw_ok = true;
        }
    }

    if ($name_and_pw_ok == false) {
        echo 'Invalid name and password';       
        echo '</body>';
        echo '</html>';
        exit;
    }
?>


<?php
foreach ($houseprices as $key => $val) {
    if ($lowprice <= $val && $highprice >= $val) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $key;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $val;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}


?>

</table>
<!-- RESUBMISSION -->
<h3>Try Again</h3>
<form action="houses.php"
      method="post">
Show houses that are between:   
<input name="lowprice" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" /> &     
<input name="highprice" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" /><br />
Username:   <input name="user" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" /><br />
Password:   <input name="pw" type="password" size="30" maxlength="30" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Show Houses" />
</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `$pw` is a string, not an array. Why are you trying to loop over it with `foreach ($pw as $key => $val)`?

Comment: The loop for finding the houses in the range looks fine. The problem is the code for checking the password. You need an array of the usernames and passwords. YOu don't need to loop over it, just `if ($users[strtolower($user)] == $pw)`

Comment: Explain how it isn't working.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a user/password list/array defined in $pw, that has been omitted here.  And the form's posted password is being assigned over the top of it.  What was an array becomes a string, that foreach block condition is never entered and satisfied and hence the password check always fails.

Comment: No theres no user/pw array. I just removed that, I thought it was removed from my post. I have edited what I posted to better show what I currently have. This imgur shows what the errror I am getting is https://imgur.com/gallery/3zKy8St